# How to change array to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object

```
           [{"displayName":"group1"},{"displayName":"group2"}]
```

I would like to change this to

```
    [{"displayName":["group1","group2"]}]
```

I searched questions similar to this, however, I don't get the logic. 
 Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
      Object.assign({}, [{"displayName":"group1"},{"displayName":"group2"}]);
```

Comment: make a choice; 1 or the other. Someone will provide the code to produce the result.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question

Comment: Great, now, show effort and get your question reopened. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this will produce the result for you, but I think you may want to consider the use of the output first.

```js
let sourceArr = [{"displayName":"group1"},{"displayName":"group2"}]

let targetArr = [{"displayName": sourceArr.map(s => s["displayName"])}];

console.log(targetArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.